# How to find an element by using DOM structure in Selenium?

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My application integrates with Google Maps and I'm trying to write some UI tests using Selenium. As a part of one of my tests, I need to find the X in the infoPopup provided by Google Maps. This element does not have any id or class that I can use directly to find it in Selenium. I can use the XPath but it would make my test very brittle to any changes from Google.

On the other hand, I can walk up the DOM structure from my custom elements (use parent and sibling) and find it very easily (this is how I am accessing it in javascript). My question is whether I can also access it the same way in Selenium.

HTML form:

```
<div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;">   
    <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -18px; top: -44px; width: 68px; height: 67px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
</div>
```

XPath: `//*[@id="map"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[13]/div[1]`

I have very limited experience with Selenium. So if there are other ways of finding elements that might help me, would love to learn about them as well.

Comment: You can get the parent of an element using `someElement/..`.  You can also cast your driver into a JSExecutor and use the DOM to access the element (but then you have to perform the click via JS as well, I believe)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `By.XPath`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='map']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[13]/div[1]"));
```

However, XPath like this will be highly unstable and hard to maintain, I don't recommend to do so.

Use something like meaningful XPath or CssSelector would be nice.

```
By.XPath("//*[@id='map']//div[./img[contains(@src, 'mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png')]]");
By.CssSelector("#map img[src$='mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png']");
```

For more info about XPath or CssSelector, please refer to [the documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).

Comment: @Nitesh Baranwal: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just beginning I would suggest you use FireBug+FirePath add on to Firefox browser. To begin with it will give you the precise xpath of the elements you highlight on the UI.[Click Here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b74KZ.png)